# How to add this @Html.AntiForgeryToken() in html page. unable send the token to controller

Tags: html, asp.net, antiforgerytoken

So far i tried the code below and if I click on the button it yeilds the following error:

```
The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted. 
If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that all machines 
  are running the same version of ASP.NET Web Pages and that the machineKey
  configuration specifies explicit encryption and validation keys. 
AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.
```

Note: I have tried this in html page only and not in cshtml page...

html code:

```html
<form action="/Account/LogOff" method="post" id="logoutForm" >
   <input type='hidden' name='__RequestVerificationToken' value='...' />
</form>

<li class="m-l-md"> 
 <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">
   <i class="fa fa-power-off"></i>
  </a>
</li>
```

can anyone suggest the solution
Thanks in advance...

Comment: How do you generate the HTML page when you are not using the razor logic?

Comment: In google charts we will only use normal  html page controller,model but not cshtml page

Comment: A static HTML page cannot have a dynamic anti forgery token. It has to be inserted somehow. It might be as easy as writing `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`, if you have a `.cshtml` file. What code are you using to load/display the HTML code you have and how do want to handle the form data in your controllers?